# passing a TSQL function database name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, dynamic

Is there any way to pass a tsql function a database name so it can perform selects on that database

```
ALTER function [dbo].[getemailjcp]
(
@DB_Name varchar(100)
)
Returns varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @out varchar (4000);
DECLARE @in varchar (1000);
Set @out = 
(select substring
((select ';' + e.email from 
(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(U.nvarchar4, 'NA') as email 
FROM [@DB_Name].dbo.Lists ...
```

Comment: Can you show your whole function instead of `...`?

Comment: May I ask what your end goal is here, in other words what is the business problem that you are trying to solve? I can't help but wonder if there's a more elegant approach waiting in the wings.

Comment: For some 200 or so Database I needed to retrieve to very different pieces of infomation. We had working code in a cusor that was taking way too long. I was trying to replace the cursor with a function, but looked at the requirements again and realized i could do what I wanted at the top procedures with two foreachdb and then joinging things up. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create dynamic SQL statement you should store procedure. For example:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @FirstID BIGINT

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@FirstID BIGINT OUTPUT'
SET @DynamicSQLStatement=N' SELECT @FirstID=MAX(ID) FROM ['+@DatabaseName+'].[dbo].[SourceTable]'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement,@ParmDefinition,@FirstID=@FirstID OUTPUT

SELECT @FirstID
```

In this example:

1. @DatabaseName is the passed as parameter to your procedure.
2. @FirstID is output parameter - this value might be return from your procedure.

Here you can find more information about "sp_executesql":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: But you can't do this *in a function*. I would assume the OP tried to move it to a function so they could call it per row of a query perhaps...

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are right that "sp_executesql" can be execute in a function, user store procedures is needed.

Answer (score 0):

a better solution might be to replace "@DatabaseName" (a char variable)with:

"DB_NAME(<@DBId>)".

You can then continue to pass in the db names, but 1st converting them to IDs in the fcn.  Also kinda resolves the contradiction of building a SQL stmt w/ a char variable in it, if using "sp_executesql" to help guard against SQL injection ("DB_NAME()" isn't a variable/can't be substituted).

So you'd have this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @FirstID BIGINT
DECLARE @DBId INT

SET @DBId = DB_ID(@Db_Name) --raise the proper security/robustness** concern if this doesn't resolve.

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@FirstID BIGINT OUTPUT'
SET @DynamicSQLStatement=N' SELECT @FirstID=MAX(ID) FROM ['+DB_NAME(@DBId)+'].[dbo].[SourceTable]'
```